# Get Sqlite database from NSData instead of file

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsdata, fmdb

I used to use FMDB to read sqlite data from a file.

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:filePath];
```

Now I want to encrypt the file. When the app opens, it will decrypt the file into NSData object.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  NSData *decryptedData = [self getDecryptedData]; 

 return YES;

}
```

Is there any way I can get FMDatabase object from NSData ? I don't want to save NSData to a file because it is decrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `FMDatabase` and *SQLite* in general is pretty much bound with file system stuff, that means there's possibly no way to do this by default.

Your options as I guess:

- use separate files for encrypted `NSData` and another one for decrypted *SQLite* DB – but this solution loses any benefit of having the first file
- store `NSData` in a file and work with temporary or in-memory *SQLite* DB (see https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#database-creation) which you need to import data in when launching and export from when shutting down
- more sophisticated method using system-wide `Security` stuff, but I have really no experience with this